# Можно ли официально купить Андроид приложение и установить его на Windows компьютер?

Tags: android, windows, кроссплатформенность

Очевидно, через специальный эмулятор.

Этот вопрос мне иногда задают пользователи (моих Андроид приложений), которые хотят пользоваться этими приложениями и на персональном компьютере.

Comment: Лучше, наверное, в поддержку Play Market-а написать.

Comment: По идее ничего для этого делать-то и не нужно. Юзер покупает в маркете с телефона. Потом ставит эмулятор с гугловыми програми. Логинится под своим акком, идёт в стор и качает приложение. Все купленные .приложения должны быть доступны и покупки внутренние тоже должны быть активированы по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо! ЮрийСПб! Да, все вроде логично! А кто-нибудь так пробовал делать?

Comment: @user, вы можете стать первым)

Comment: Пускай качают через эмулятор и играют. В чем проблема?

Comment: @EraNewGames, платное приложение